# Postgres sql in return all when array empty without dynamic sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I came into a problem in `postgres sql function`, I need to return all records when the array of integer is empty.

For now I am using `dynamic sql` to achieve it with `if statement` checking if the array is empty so don't concat `in statement` in the query.
I want to know if there is another way to achieve it without `dynamic sql`?

eg using dynamic sql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testme() RETURNS TABLE(Title text) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
one int[];
BEGIN
one:= '{}';

RAISE NOTICE 'value:%', array_length(one,1);
if array_length(one,1) > 0 THEN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT  "Title" from "Tickets" where "TicketID"  
IN(SELECT(UNNEST($1)));'  USING one;
ELSE
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT "Title"  from "Tickets"';

END IF;
END
$$;
SELECT testme();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select  "Title"
from "Tickets"
where
    "TicketID" = any (one)
    or
    cardinality(one) = 0;
```

`cardinality` returns 0 for an empty array whereas `array_length` returns `null`

Comment: Hmm - never noticed that about `array_length` before. Presumably to do with not knowing how many dimensions any particular array could have. Thanks Clodoaldo.

Comment: thanks it worked!!! btw is it true that any have bad performance vs in i showed in my answer?
 also the answer works with IN(SELECT(UNNEST(one)))

Comment: @duduhayo They should behave the same.